# Code to navigate web pages does not produce the expected result (Selenium)

Tags: javascript, selenium

### Code

```js
(async function() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  try {
    await driver.get(stockLink);
    if (await driver.findElement(By.linkText('View at Amazon.co.uk')) === true) {
      let amazonLink = await driver
        .wait(until.elementLocated(By.linkText('View at Amazon.co.uk')), 5000);
      await amazonLink.click();
    }
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }

})();
```

### Result

Calling `await driver.get(stockLink);` opens the page (`stockLink`), however the link in the `if` statement (`amazonLink`) does not open (which is part of the content on the stockLink page)

### Expected result

Both `stockLink` and `amazonLink` should open (where `amazonLink` is a link on `stockLink`'s page)

### Major edit

I appear to have fixed the issue. I'm not sure what I did to fix this (apart from removing the `if` statement), but it appears to be fixed. If I encounter another error, I will search for it or open another question.

Comment: findElement will return a webelement reference or throw.  It will never equal "true".  Instead you can use findElements and check for an empty array.

Comment: I'll try to implement this. Thanks.

Comment: @pcalkins Hm.. Could you show me an example? I'm not sure if I'm implementing it right.

Comment: I have no experience using Selenium with Javascript.  But seems like you don't really need the "if" here.  Just use the webdriverwait.  It'll throw timeout/not found if it doesn't appear within the timeout period.

Comment: Alright. I'll see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: IDK. Whatever I try seems to not work.

Comment: Anyone got any other ideas?